# Accuracy limitations of singular value decomposition?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

in the process of working on a physics problem I have found the need to use the singular value decomposition function built into Mathematica. I have encountered what seem to be limitations to the accuracy of the SVD when the elements of the matrix we are decomposing become large. Let me be more explicit:

The matrix to decompose is defined in terms of the tensor which can be constructed by running the following code:

```
T = Table[0, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}];

Part[Part[Part[T, 1], 1], 1] = e^(3 (KK + h));
Part[Part[Part[T, 1], 3], 3] = 3 e^(-KK + h);
Part[Part[Part[T, 2], 2], 2] = e^(3 (KK - h));
Part[Part[Part[T, 2], 3], 3] = 3 e^-(KK + h);
T = Normal[Symmetrize[T]];
```

The matrix that we want to use the SVD on is then

```
Partition[Flatten[TensorContract[TensorProduct[T,T],{3,4}]],9]
```

Now we just have to choose some values for the parameters $KK, h$ and let the SVD do its magic. Since it might be relevant to a diagnosis, here is my code for running the SVD:

```
singout = SingularValueDecomposition[
N[Partition[Flatten[TensorContract[TensorProduct[T, T], {3, 4}]], 
9]], Tolerance -> 0]
```

In the context of my physics problem, it's reasonable to take $h=0$, so let's do that. If we run the SVD with $KK=1$, I find that the code works exactly as intended: the input matrix is reproduced almost exactly by the matrix product

```
u.w.Transpose[v]
```

where $u, w$, and $v$ are as defined in the SVD documentation. There is a bit of numerical noise, but nothing goes dramatically wrong.

In contrast, we can take $KK=10$, which is, again, a reasonable idea in the context of my physics problem. I'm not sure how to format matrices here, so I've attached a picture of the output. The first matrix is the exact input, and the second is the SVD output, chopped at $10^{-10}$ to avoid clutter. There are some small discrepancies between the two matrices, but by far the most important error is the bottom-left entry of the SVD output: it is returning zero instead of a number on the order of $10^8$. I need to understand why this is happening so that I can control the approximation from the SVD appropriately. Any suggestions for understanding this would be very helpful.

I should perhaps also note that this seems to be a problem in general for large values of $KK$, but I'm not sure why that is the case. Thanks for any help you can offer.

[image: Pictures of relevant matrices: the first is the exact input and the second is the reconstructed matrix from the singular value decomposition.]

Comment: Change the precision in `N` to an appropriate value, e.g. 20 gets 4.85165*10^8 in LL corner...

Comment: Really? I just tried to reproduce that on my machine and there was no change. I increased the working/machine precision and purposely left the second argument for N empty to avoid that problem, but putting it in manually changes nothing for me.

Comment: Beats me then - try restarting your kernel - looking at the result with appropriate `N` setting matches your top (input matrix) exactly when chopped...

Comment: Hmm, that's bizarre. I closed everything completely and didn't change any internal precision settings, just adjusted the argument of N, and that didn't help me at all. What is happening...

Comment: I'll post my run as answer (too big for comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
T = Table[0, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}];

Part[Part[Part[T, 1], 1], 1] = E^(3 (KK + h));
Part[Part[Part[T, 1], 3], 3] = 3 E^(-KK + h);
Part[Part[Part[T, 2], 2], 2] = E^(3 (KK - h));
Part[Part[Part[T, 2], 3], 3] = 3 E^-(KK + h);
T = Normal[Symmetrize[T]];

h = 0;
KK = 10;
im = Partition[Flatten[TensorContract[TensorProduct[T, T], {3, 4}]], 
   9];
singout = SingularValueDecomposition[N[im, 20], Tolerance -> 0];

{u, w, v} = singout;
res = (u.w.Transpose[v]);

N@MinMax[res - im]
```

> {-4.12231*10^-9, 3.54693*10^-41}

As you can see, very small difference... and as noted, chopping and comparing visually it matches your image.

Comment: I see, thanks for posting the code. This works correctly on my machine - I realized that the only difference was I defined KK=10.0 instead of KK=10. I didn't realize that the decimal point could change things so dramatically. Incidentally, do you know if there is a way to get around that? In general I will want to use non-integer values of KK, so I'll have to deal with this as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @user46073 The short answer: ``5.2`30`` indicates the value $5.2$ expressed with 30 digits of precision. Alternatively you can use e.g. [`Rationalize[number, 0]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) to get an arbitrary (i.e. infinite) precision rational representation of `number`. Take a look at [Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html) and [Numerical Precision Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html).

Comment: @mflynn, in general, any number with a decimal point in *Mathematica* is *inexact*, and unless you specify the precision like in Marco's comment, the precision defaults to machine precision. Which will be fast, but not necessarily numerically reliable.